# Title changes in HNQs make browsers mark them as 'unvisited'

Tags: feature-request, edits, hyperlinks, hot-questions, title

In the below example it shows one link as visited another as unvisited. However I have previously read both posts.

[image]

Can the URL be changed either to short form, or to not include the title.

Comment: It’s not just HNQ questions; this also happens in any questions list, e.g. the Newest Questions.